# Regular expression breaking in browsers?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-11

This regular expression seems to break in Chrome, Firefox and IE11...

```
'abc(def'.match('\((\w*)')
```

Is there anything wrong with it?  Is there a better way to escape the ( character?

If I do it this way, they are happy:

```
/\((\w*)/.exec('abc(def')
```

Comment: Some online testing tools accept this, but of course, they likely execute it in regular expression format, or escape the \ characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to escape the `\` characters if you construct the regular expression from a string literal:

```
'abc(def'.match('\\((\\w*)')
```

Or simply use a regular expression literal:

```
'abc(def'.match(/\((\w*)/)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your regex must be enclosed between `/` instead of `'`:

```
'abc(def'.match(/\((\w*)/)
```